# Use String or Object for data in Java NIO-based distributed system?

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to send data different data (Security keys, encrypted message )in distributed system that use Java NIO. my question is what is the best way to send data? . I am currently sending data using base64 encoding and append different data in to a single string. Is this good or it will be good to send data using java serializable object.

please help 
Thanx

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. I don't think there's any way for someone to say what "the best way" is without a lot more information: do you have security concerns, or just compatibility issues? Are both sides running Java? Are you worried about data size? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably avoid using Strings and Java default serialization - that's likely to be pretty inefficient and give you a lot of overhead.

I'd recommend looking at a library like Kryonet or Netty instead.

Alternatively you can create your own serialisation code using NIO, but that's quite complex to get right and a lot of work....